# Embed a plot into HTML using FastAPI and Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I am trying to display a plot that is embedded into an HTML response and I'm having no luck. I am using Jinja2 for templates. I have a `plot.png` saved in my local root directory and I am trying to embed it into the HTML response.

I am getting the following messages in my terminal:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49509 - "POST /analytics HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49509 - "GET /plot.png HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

So my guess is that my `plot.png` that is saved locally cannot be accessed by my app. I am pretty new to this, so any pointers would be much appreciated!

---

`main.py`:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates/")


@app.get("/analytics")
async def get_plot(request: Request):
    result = "Please select a user: "

    return templates.TemplateResponse('plot_template.html', context={'request': request, 'result': result})


@app.post("/analytics")
async def get_plot(request: Request, username: str = Form(...)):
    user_email = username + "@mycompany.com"
    result = user_email

    return templates.TemplateResponse('plot_template.html', context={'request': request, 'result': result})
```

`plot_template.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="username">Choose a user:</label>
            <select id="username" name="username">
                <option value="demo">Demo User</option>
                <option value="not_verified_user">Not Verified User</option>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p>Result: {{ result }}</p>
    <img src="plot.png" alt="Plot will display after a user is selected">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/? Make sure this is just a subdirectory in your project, _do not_ serve a random directory on your computer as a static file directory, since all files and subfiles will be available through the service.

Comment: I am able to display my plot when I specify it via `FileResponse`, but in that case it is the only thing that is displayed. My problem is embedding this into my HTML template - so I guess my question is why am I able to serve the file as a `FileResponse`, but unable to fill in an HTML template with it?

Comment: You'll have to configure a `StaticFiles` instance as shown in the link above. That will allow you to serve a specific file through FastAPI (since the HTML returned has a _reference_ to the image, the browser then makes a second request to fetch that image, and FastAPI has to know how to handle that URL as well - thus, configuring it to serve a specific directory as the root for static files). When you use a FileResponse you're just telling FastAPI "for this endpoint (i.e. URL) serve this specific file)". Since the browser makes a second request to fetch the image, you need to return it.

Comment: Thank you, managed to get it to work! I set up the `static` directory and changed the image source to `static/plot.png`

Comment: You can use `{{ url_for('static', path='plot.png') }}` to have FastAPI generate the URL for you in the template; no need to know about whether it's `/static` or `/s` etc.